# Sort NSFetchRequest by calculation result

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I have a dataset of points with latitude and longitude values and I want to retrieve them and sort them by the distance to the user's current location. Currently, I have the following:

```
mainMoc.performBlockAndWait {
            // Fetching data from CoreData
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pointLatitude BETWEEN {%f,%f} AND pointLongitude BETWEEN {%f,%f}", (latitude-0.03), (latitude+0.03), (longitude-0.03), (longitude+0.03))
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("PointPrimary", inManagedObjectContext: self.mainMoc)
            fetchRequest.entity = entity

            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "pointTitle", ascending: false)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

            do {
                points = try self.mainMoc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [PointPrimary]

            } catch {
                let jsonError = error as NSError
                NSLog("\(jsonError), \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
                abort()
            }
        }
```

So currently I'm only sorting it based on the title. But how would I proceed if I wanted to calculate the distance to say a CLLocationCoordinate2D and sort the fetchRequest results based on that?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

`NSFetchRequest` can't use properties other than those defined in the model (and stored in the database) as sort descriptors, so you'll have to resort to in-memory sorting. Define a `distance` method on your `PointPrimary` class that performs the appropriate computation and do:

```
let sortedPoints = points.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "distance", ascending: true)])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Basically you'll use an `NSSortDescriptor` with custom comparator.

The trick is to use `"self"` as key for the `NSSortDescriptor`, which will pass the fetched objects into the comparator.

```
var userLocation : CLLocation // get that from somewhere
var distanceCompare : NSComparator = {
    (obj1: AnyObject!, obj2: AnyObject!) -> NSComparisonResult in
    let lng1 = obj1.valueForKey("pointLongitude") as! CLLocationDegrees
    let lat1 = obj1.valueForKey("pointLatitude") as! CLLocationDegrees
    let p1Location : CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat1, longitude: lng1)
    let p1DistanceToUserLocation = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(p1Location)

    let lng2 = obj2.valueForKey("pointLongitude") as! CLLocationDegrees
    let lat2 = obj2.valueForKey("pointLatitude") as! CLLocationDegrees
    let p2Location : CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat1, longitude: lng1)
    let p2DistanceToUserLocation = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(p2Location)

    if (p1DistanceToUserLocation > p2DistanceToUserLocation) {
        return .OrderedDescending
    } else if (p1DistanceToUserLocation < p2DistanceToUserLocation) {
        return .OrderedAscending
    } else {
        return .OrderedSame
    }
}

var distanceSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "self", ascending: true, comparator: distanceCompare)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [distanceSortDescriptor]
```